# cuando quiero instalar firebase me sale este error de npm de 22 vulnerabilidades 2 moderado 17 high 3 critical. ya intente de todo y no puedo solucion

Tags: nodejs, firebase, npm

[image: npm vulnerabilidad]
npm vulnerabilidad error no me deja instalar firebase

Comment: No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por cierto... ¿Leíste lo que dice el mensaje de color verde? :)

Comment: pudiste encontrar solucion? :,c